# Pick up an url within a string

Tags: php, spam-prevention

Hi all I am trying a quick and dirty solution for stopping a comment spammer on my site, trying to pick up this url "https://www.change.org/en-GB/petitions/rockstar-games-release-pc-games-for-the-linux-operating-system" in a bunch of text like so:

```
        if (strpos($_POST['text'], "https://www.change.org/en-GB/petitions/rockstar-games-release-games-for-linux") == true)
        {
            header("Location: /home/banned");
        }
```

Sadly that doesn't seem to work, is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

from php

```
strpos()

Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.
```

it wont return `TRUE` so do it like `!==FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

[strpos](http://php.net/strpos) returns "Returns the position of where the needle exists" or "Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.". Thus, you should test whether not not it returns false:

```
if (strpos(...) === false) {
    // needle was not found
}
```

In your case you need to check for the negation (i.e. needle was found):

```
if (strpos($_POST['text'], "https://...") !== false) {
    header("Location: /home/banned");
}
```

Note the extract equals sign in the both operators (`===` and `!==`), which is there to [make comparison type strict](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). If you don't use type strict comparison and needle is found at position `0`, you get a false negative result (`0` is interpreted to be equal to `false`).

Comment: Shouldnt that be `!== false`

Answer (score 0):

You should use !== false instead of == true

```
   if (strpos($_POST['text'], "https://www.change.org/en-GB/petitions/rockstar-games-release-games-for-linux") !== false)
    {
        header("Location: /home/banned");
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: That still makes me script continue as if it isn't found, when it's clearly in the text i'm checking against.

Comment: What's the $_POST['text'] content ?

Comment: That url and nothing more as a test.

Comment: Impossible, when I assigned $_POST['text'] the same string as url you provided I was redirected to banned url